# Transfer input from prompt() into a text field

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a HTML page in which when the start button is being pressed, a prompt box will appear to prompt the user to enter his/her name. When user enters his/her name and confirms the input, it would appear on the black box (as shown in the code) with white text color. I am not sure of how to "transfer" the value from prompt() to text field. I know the value of the input fields are empty by default.

```js
function myFunction() {
  var person = prompt("Please enter your name");
  if (person != null) {
       person = document.getElementById(input).value;
  }
}
```

```css
#input{
  width: 15%;
  padding: 50px 50px;
  margin: 8px 0;
  background-color: #191818;
  color: white;

}

#input1 {
  width: 15%;
  padding: 50px 50px;
  margin: 8px 0;
  background-color: #7C7878;
  color: white;

}

.btnEdit{
    width: 30px;
    margin: 5px;
    display: block;

    font-weight:bold;  
    text-align:center;
    font-size:10px;   
    line-height:15px;
}
```

```html
<h2>Part 3</h2>
<button onclick="return myFunction()" id="strt" value="Start">Start</button>
<button onclick="return reset()" id="clr" value="Clear">Clear</button> <br />
<br>
<input type="text" id="input" style="text-align:center;" name="input"/>
<button id="swap" value="Swap"  class="btnEdit">--></button>
<button id="swap1" value="Swap1"  class="btnEdit"><--</button>
<input type="text" id="input1" value="" style="text-align:center;" name="input1"/>
```

Expected output would be for the user to enter his/her name in the prompt and upon confirmation, his/her name will appear in the text field in black with white text colors.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You just need to swap it.

```
person = document.getElementById(input).value;
```

The above is wrong. It should be:

```
document.getElementById("input").value = person;
```

And you need to update the `"input"` too. It's not a constant.

```js
function myFunction() {
  var person = prompt("Please enter your name");
  if (person != null) {
    document.getElementById("input").value = person;
  }
}
```

```css
#input {
  width: 15%;
  padding: 50px 50px;
  margin: 8px 0;
  background-color: #191818;
  color: white;
}

#input1 {
  width: 15%;
  padding: 50px 50px;
  margin: 8px 0;
  background-color: #7C7878;
  color: white;
}

.btnEdit {
  width: 30px;
  margin: 5px;
  display: block;
  font-weight: bold;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 10px;
  line-height: 15px;
}
```

```html
<h2>Part 3</h2>
<button onclick="return myFunction()" id="strt" value="Start">Start</button>
<button onclick="return reset()" id="clr" value="Clear">Clear</button> <br />
<br>
<input type="text" id="input" style="text-align:center;" name="input" />
<button id="swap" value="Swap" class="btnEdit">--></button>
<button id="swap1" value="Swap1" class="btnEdit"><--</button>
<input type="text" id="input1" value="" style="text-align:center;" name="input1" />
```

Comment: @gaetanoM Thanks for the edit mate. I added the snippet too.

Comment: Oh my! Thank you! Rookie mistake there.

Comment: @alonelycoder Happens. Always remember the one that's gonna get the value goes on the left. Constants or expressions come on the right. Technically, in simple words, data travels from right to left.

Answer (score -1):

```js
function myFunction() {
  var person = prompt("Please enter your name");
  if (person != null) {
        document.getElementById('input').value = person;
  }
}
```

```css
#input{
  width: 15%;
  padding: 50px 50px;
  margin: 8px 0;
  background-color: #191818;
  color: white;

}

#input1 {
  width: 15%;
  padding: 50px 50px;
  margin: 8px 0;
  background-color: #7C7878;
  color: white;

}

.btnEdit{
    width: 30px;
    margin: 5px;
    display: block;

    font-weight:bold;  
    text-align:center;
    font-size:10px;   
    line-height:15px;
}
```

```html
<h2>Part 3</h2>
<button onclick="return myFunction()" id="strt" value="Start">Start</button>
<button onclick="return reset()" id="clr" value="Clear">Clear</button> <br />
<br>
<input type="text" id="input" style="text-align:center;" name="input"/>
<button id="swap" value="Swap"  class="btnEdit">--></button>
<button id="swap1" value="Swap1"  class="btnEdit"><--</button>
<input type="text" id="input1" value="" style="text-align:center;" name="input1"/>
```

Comment: So how's this answer better than the other one posted 20 mins ago? It just looks like a copy of mine, no explanation and nothing. This is one example of a low quality and plagiarised answer. Just telling.